# clojurescript + reagent + reagent-material-ui: Trying to loop through list

Tags: material-ui, clojurescript, reagent

So I've been using clojurescript and reagent only for a couple of days and I'm trying to create a simple personal website. I set the project up with shadow-clj for hot reloading.

First I imported the required material-ui stuff:

```
(:require [reagent-material-ui.icons.home :refer [home]]
          [reagent-material-ui.icons.apps :refer [apps]]
          [reagent-material-ui.core.list :refer [list]]
          [reagent-material-ui.core.list-item :refer [list-item]]
          [reagent-material-ui.core.list-item-icon :refer [list-item-icon]]
          [reagent-material-ui.core-list-item-text :refer [list-item-text]])
```

Then I defined the items I want in my navbar:

```
(def menu-items '({:list-icon [home] :list-text "Home"}
                  {:list-icon [apps] :list-text "Portfolio"}))
```

And then I tried to loop through the `menu-items` and put them in reagent components:

```
(defn navbar []
  [list
    (map (fn [item]
           [list-item
             [list-item-icon (:list-icon item)]
             [list-item-text (:list-text item)]])
         menu-items)])
```

Now when I reload the code only the text from `:list-text` is shown but no icons. I've already tried to show the icons without any loop and that worked perfectly.

There is no error output in the console only two warnings:

```
Warning: Every element in a seq should have a unique :key: ([#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] [#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] [home]] [#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] "Home"]] [#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] [#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] [apps]] [#object[reagent.impl.template.NativeWrapper] "Portfolio"]] 
 (in webapp.core.page >  > webapp.components.index.home >  > webapp.components.navbar.navbar)
```

and

```
Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: webapp.components.index.home, webapp.components.navbar.navbar, webapp.core.page
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue is that the icon is a Reagent component. Defining menu-items as a quoted list gives Reagent `'home` instead of `home`. You might solve that problem by defining menu-items as a vector, without quoting.